# Video & image processing in Spartan-6 FPGA

Tags: fpga, matlab, spartan

I'm very new to FPGA.  I got a Spartan-6 from Digilent. As my final year project I want to do image processing through it.  How can MATLAB & Simulink be used for this?  How should the camera be connected to the board?  Through HDMI or USB?

Comment: Which camera are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You're very new to FPGAs and you want to do image processing?  I'm no expert but that sounds like biting off a lot more than you can chew.  Can you answer any of these questions:

- What image processing algorithm do
  you want to implement?  Can you
  express the algorithm in pseudocode?
- What format is the image you want to
  process?  Bitmap?  JPEG?  What color
  depth?
- What image sensor have you chosen? 
  What resolution is it?  Is it
  grayscale or color?
- Do you have a basic block diagram of
  the system?  Can you show us?

If you haven't thought about any of these questions or don't understand the terms I'm using then this project probably isn't for you.

Comment: Very sound advice, despite the harsh tone. Also, have you considered whether FPGA is really the way to go? There seem to be a lot of FPGA-for-FPGA's-sake projects going around these days.

Comment: I don't find the answer to be harsh, just some good questions the poster should ask himself.

Comment: Don't say that! He's the AngryEE, he's got a reputation to protect! ;)

Comment: So true, but I try not to be too angry because it puts people off.  Still, I think some people need to realize that the cool-sounding projects they hear about online or in magazines represent weeks or months of work and are not straightforward, simple and fun.

Answer (score 4):

Big question - I've [started a series of articles](http://parallelpoints.com/taxonomy/term/21) about developing image processing systems in FPGAs.  It's not complete yet, but it may give you some ideas. [The first one is here](http://parallelpoints.com/node/46)

If you can get a sensor which directly connects to the FPGA pins (ie a clock, couple of sync pins and some data pins) you'll get going much quicker than having to pull data over USB/Firewire/etc.

---

Update: 2022-01-23

Although the original links above appear to be invalid at the moment, versions of those webpages are currently available at the links below:

- Series of articles about developing image processing systems in FPGAs:
  [Copy of 2012 version of the webpage at Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120109075255/http://parallelpoints.com/taxonomy/term/21)
- First article in the series:
  [Copy of 2012 version of the webpage at Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120109074716/http://parallelpoints.com/node/46)
  [Live version of that webpage](https://parallelpoints.com/image-processing-001/)

Comment: Fantastic blog you have there!!

Comment: Unfortunately, the links in this answer are now dead.

Comment: @DaveTweed - Thanks for highlighting the problem. I've added links to the best copies of those pages I can find on Archive.org and the new URL on the live site for one of the links.

Comment: @SamGibson thanks for adding those links - I thought I had got redirects in place when I  rebuilt the site a few years ago, but it seems I missed some :(  I'll take another look !

Comment: @MartinThompson - Thanks for your comment :) Obviously it's *your* answer, so please do remove or update anything I added. This was why I didn't change your original text and just added onto the end, so that my changes can easily be deleted when links have been fixed etc.

Comment: @SamGibson - appreciated - thanks :) (It turns out, I appear to have lost the images (or at least the links to them) in the transition from Drupal many years ago, so it's more than a quick re-direct.  I shall have the delve the backups :( For now archive.org is what we have...